# How can i distinct the coordinate system the Mapkit is current used, specially in China?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

it seems that MapKit selects map provider based on the device is located. In China it will use AutoNavi maps, and else it will use the default Apple maps, but their coordinate system are different, China uses a standard coordinate system called GCJ-02, it has GPS offset problem. I want to distinct the coordinate system the Mapkit is current used so i can do something different, is there any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using an alternative to Apple's maps such as [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which is based on open data.

Comment: Thanks for you advise, but our project is based on Apple's map for a long time, now I use some reference point to check if the map has offseted to temporarily solution this problem

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this interesting article](http://www.sinosplice.com/life/archives/2013/07/16/a-more-complete-ios-solution-to-the-china-gps-offset-problem), there is a C# implementation of a converter [here](https://on4wp7.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21455#353936).

[Mardinate](https://github.com/Mardinate/Mardinate) is the Objective-C implementation of that code. The conversion is not perfect, and China is roughly defined:

> You’ll note that the code interprets that anything within China needs this conversion, anything outside of China, doesn’t. And that China is defined as anything between Latitude 0.83 to 56 and Longitude 72 to 138. I think there’s a few countries caught in that rectangle that might object.

It is a pity that MapKit doesn't allow to make the conversion, but I can't seem to find an answer online. Maybe they are just not allowed to do it.